# Xamarin.forms's tabbedPage SetIcon not working dynamically on Android.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms. 
If you look youtube or any google apps on Android. 
Only selected tab icon would be highlighted. 
So I want to apply that.

I'm using Appcompat toolbar for Xamarin.forms.

My code is...

```
        this.CurrentPageChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            int index = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    NavigationPage navpage = this.Children[i] as NavigationPage;
                    if (navpage != null)
                    {
                        if (i == index)
                            navpage.Icon = "x3_tabbaricon_1" + index;
                        else
                            navpage.Icon = "x3_tabbaricon_2" + index + "_";
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

It's working correctly on iOS. 
But nothing happens on Android. 
{ContentPage}.SetIcon should be called. but It's not affected to any of tabs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer. 
I have to use selector for Android.